# unable to fetch json data in listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

This is the main activity and i have **asynktask**, **jsonparsor** files.. and i want to fetch the json dat which is the following format :

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "records": [
        {
            "member_id": "10",
            "member_name": "RavinderKaur",
            "gender": "1",
            "dob": "15-7-2014",
            "email": "rv@gmail.com",
            "contact_no": "1234567891",
            "address": "",
            "member_password": "25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad",
            "member_designation": "",
            "created_date": "2014-05-18 22:49:34"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends Activity{

ListView mProfile ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mProfile = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProfile);

}
    //getting link with json and asynktask

public void getdata(){
    JSONGetRequest jRequest = JSONGetRequest
            .getSingleInstance(MyProfileActivity.this);
    jRequest.execute(Tags.url);

    try {

        JSONObject result = jRequest.execute().get();

                    String status = result.getString("status");

                if (status.equals("1")){

                    ArrayList<MyProfile> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyProfile>();

                JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("records");
        for(int i=0; i<=array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            MyProfile objBeans = new MyProfile();
            objBeans.setName(json.getString("name"));
            arraylist.add(objBeans);

        }   
    }
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            //doing try here for inserting data into adapter 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
        mProfile.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

This is my JSONParsor File

```
package com.example.capo.net;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

private static InputStream iStream = null;

private static String json = "";
private static JSONObject jObj = null;

public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) {

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                builder.append(line);
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        // jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;

}
}
```

This is my AsynckTask file :

```
package com.example.capo.net;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class JSONGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

private static Context mContext;
private static JSONGetRequest singleInstance;
private ProgressDialog mDialog;


public static JSONGetRequest getSingleInstance(Context context) {

    singleInstance = new JSONGetRequest();

    mContext = context;

    return singleInstance;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    mDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    mDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);

        return json;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return null;

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    mDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

This file is used for Beans :

```
package com.example.capo.beans;

public class MyProfile {

public String name , email,gender, dob, mobile,
 designation;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}
}
```

This is my Registration file from that i am able to store the data properly :

```
package com.example.capo.ui;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.capo.R;
import com.example.capo.net.JSONGetRequest;
import com.example.capo.services.NotificationServices;
import com.example.capo.services.Tags;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RformActivity extends Activity implements OnDateSetListener,
    OnClickListener {

// declaration of variables

private EditText mFirstName, mLastName, mEmail, mDob, mMobile,
        mPassword, mConfirmPassword, mdesignation;
private RadioButton mMale, mFemale;
private ImageView mSubmit;

public static String number, password;

private String gender;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rform);

    // reference from their Ids

    mFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
    mLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    mDob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDob);
    mMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMobile);

    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    mConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConfirmPassword);
    mdesignation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDesignation);
    mMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
    mFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);
    mSubmit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    mDob.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    if(mMale.isChecked()){gender = "0";}else{ gender = "1"; }


}

// to show the date in given pattern
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) {

    String s = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    mDob.setText(s);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (arg0 == mDob) {

        DatePickerDialog dt = new DatePickerDialog(RformActivity.this,
                (OnDateSetListener) RformActivity.this, 2014, 07, 15);
        dt.show();

    }

    if (arg0 == mSubmit) {

        String firstname = mFirstName.getText().toString();
        String lastname = mLastName.getText().toString();
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        String dob = mDob.getText().toString();
        number = mMobile.getText().toString();
        password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        String confirmpassword = mConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
        String designation = mdesignation.getText().toString(); 

        if (firstname.equals("") || lastname.equals("") || email.equals("") || dob.equals("")
                || number.equals("") 
                || designation.equals("") || password.equals("")
                || confirmpassword.equals("")) {

            NotificationServices.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Fill the empty fields");

        }else if (isEmail(email)){

        if (number.length() < 10 || number.length() == 11) {

            NotificationServices.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Enter correct number");

        }else if (password.length() < 8) {

            NotificationServices.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Password should not be less than Eight");

        }else if (password.equals(confirmpassword)) {

            NotificationServices.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Checking for Sign Up");

            JSONGetRequest jRequest = JSONGetRequest
                    .getSingleInstance(RformActivity.this);

            try {

                String url = (Tags.url + "request=registration&name="
                        + (firstname+lastname) + "&gender=" + gender +"&email=" + email + "&mobile=" + number
                        + "&dob=" + dob + "&password=" + password + "&designation" + designation).replaceAll(" ", "%20");

                JSONObject result = jRequest.execute(url).get();

                if (result.getString("status").equals("1")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RformActivity.this,
                            HomeTabActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } else {

            NotificationServices.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Password not matches");

        }
    }
}
}

private boolean isEmail(String email) {

    if (email.contains("@")
            && email.contains(".")
            && email.indexOf("@") == email.lastIndexOf("@")
            && email.indexOf("@") != (email.indexOf(".") + 1)
            && (email.indexOf("@") + 1) != email.indexOf(".")
            && (!email.contains("^")) && (!email.contains(" "))
            && (!email.contains("-")) && (!email.contains("--"))) {

        return true;

    } else {

        NotificationServices.showToast(getApplicationContext(),
                "Enter correct Email.");
        return false;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes

Change this

```
 ArrayList<MyProfile> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyProfile>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There is no json value with the key `name`

```
arraylist.add(json.getString("member_name")); // its member_name
```

Change your for loop to

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){ // you will get index out of bound excpetin
// index starts from 0
```

Your adapter will be

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
// this is just to display name
```

The is also other way using Custom ArrayAdapter

```
  if (status.equals("1")){

  ArrayList<MyProfile> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyProfile>();

  JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("records");
  for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
  JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
  MyProfile objBeans = new MyProfile();
  objBeans.setId(json.getString("member_id").toString());
  objBeans.setName(json.getString("member_name").toString());
  arraylist.add(mprofile);
 }
```

Then

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,arraylist);
```

Then

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyProfile>
{
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<MyProfile> list;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MyProfile> list) {
        super(context, 0,list);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list=list;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,parent,false);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        MyProfile mp = list.get(position);
        tv.setText(mp.getName());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With CustomAdapter you could also display other items. Just add one more text view in custom layout

Have getter and setter in `MyProfile.java`

```
 objBeans.setName(json.getString("member_id").toString());
 objBeans.setName(json.getString("member_name").toString());
```

Display in textview using list

Edit:

public class MyProfileActivity extends Activity implements Returnjson{

ListView mProfile ;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mProfile = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProfile);
     JSONGetRequest jRequest = JSONGetRequest
                .getSingleInstance(MyProfileActivity.this);
        jRequest.execute("http://stagging.jandeccpl.com/testing/android_traning/carpool/ws/api.php?request=login&username=1234567891&password=12345678");

}
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyProfile>
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ArrayList<MyProfile> list;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MyProfile> list) {
            super(context, 0,list);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.list=list;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.second,parent,false);
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            MyProfile mp = list.get(position);
            tv.setText(mp.getId());
            tv1.setText(mp.getName());
            return convertView;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void returnjson(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          try
            {
          //  JSONObject result = new JSONObject(load());

            String status = result.getString("status");

        if (status.equals("1")){

            ArrayList<MyProfile> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyProfile>();

         JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("records");
         for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
         JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
         MyProfile mprofile = new MyProfile();
         mprofile.setId(json.getString("member_id").toString());
         mprofile.setName(json.getString("member_name").toString());
         arraylist.add(mprofile);
         }  
         CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MyProfileActivity.this,arraylist);
         mProfile.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
            }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Returnjson.java

```
public interface Returnjson {
  public void returnjson(JSONObject json);
}
```

JSONGetRequest.java

```
public class JSONGetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static JSONGetRequest singleInstance;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    Returnjson rt;

    public static JSONGetRequest getSingleInstance(Context context) {

        singleInstance = new JSONGetRequest();

        mContext = context;

        return singleInstance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        rt= (Returnjson) mContext;
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        mDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);

            return json;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mDialog.dismiss();
        rt.returnjson(result);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you i shall use your way ..but i want you see my above posted code .. i have edited yet .. i posted all the codes thank you again

Comment: @user3663727 i have seen your post. `ArrayAdapter<String>` adapter of string type . `ArrayList<MyProfile>` arraylist of MyProfile. Do you understand the mistake you are doing??. With arraylist you populate listview.

Comment: @user3663727 the for loop is not right. the parsing is not right. You are better off using custom adapter coz it helps displaying id and other items later

Comment: ok i am using your way if any problem will occur i shall post again , thanks to all friends for helping me god bless you all

Comment: arraylist.add(mprofile); now here is the problem , so what to do now

Comment: @user3663727 the problem is?? it should be `arraylist.add(objBeans)`. Its a typo error should be obvious

Comment: ok thanks now i am working

Comment: how to use this line JSONObject result = jRequest.execute().get(); error here now

Comment: @user3663727 how do i know what is the error. AN how do i know what is jRequest?? Require more info. Without code not possible to solve any further. post `JSONGetRequest.java`

Comment: you can see the above myprofile.java code there is JSONGetRequest jRequest = JSONGetRequest
    .getSingleInstance(MyProfileActivity.this);
  jRequest.execute(Tags.url);

  try {
   
   JSONObject result = jRequest.execute().get();
      
   String status = result.getString("status");
     
   if (status.equals("1")){

Comment: that does not give me any info on what `jRequest.execute().get();` returns and why do you have a call to execute twice `jRequest.execute(Tags.url);` and then `jRequest.execute().get();`. Need more info. Pls re- read my previous comment

Comment: @user3663727 wrong formatting led to the confusion. pls format your post properly. 1. There is no need to call `get()` on `AsyncTask`. 2. Use a interface as a callback to the activity to get the result back in activity. Lots to be rectified

Comment: you can see JSONGetRequest.java on top

Comment: friend i am new in stackoverflow similarly i am new in android so for problem occuring sorry for that .. but can you do change the code for me

Comment: @user3663727 there is a lot that needs to be rectified. Not possible to rectify everything. You better understand the basics of AsyncTask first. If you are new to android the first thing you should do is read the docs and understand it

Comment: please see my Registration file from the top then i hope you will be able to understand that how am i using everything

Comment: @user3663727 i need not see what is not related to the problem. THe problem is you are calling `get()`. you need a way to get the parsed json back to the Activity. Pls re-read my comments for you understand what needs to be done instead of asking me to read you whole post again.

Comment: @user3663727 give me the url where the json is. i will try posting a full solution

Comment: i have only this http://stagging.jandeccpl.com/testing/android_traning/carpool/ws/api.php?request=login&username=1234567891&password=12345678

Comment: @user3663727 edited my post. makes the changes and it will work and pls read the docs before copy pasting coz you will end up asking questions again if you don't read the docs

Answer (score 0):

change this line `json.getString("name")`
to

```
json.getString("member_name")
```

Because your json doesn't contain `"name"`

**edit**
You are inserting MyProfile object list in string adapter,that's wrong.
change this

```
ArrayList<MyProfile> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyProfile>();
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and this

```
MyProfile objBeans = new MyProfile();
            objBeans.setName(json.getString("name"));
            arraylist.add(objBeans);
```

to

```
arraylist.add(json.getString("member_name"));
```

Comment: but can you tell me that my way to fetch the data in  right or am i doing wrong because not any error while running .. but data not getting fetch ....

Comment: Are you not getting in JSONException?

Comment: showing error on arraylist     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
        mProfile.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Friend actually i have JSONParsor , and askytask seperate files ..and i able to store the data in mysql via php.. but i unable to get the data which i want to show in listview

Comment: yes Giru bai i used just like you told but still not happend anything

Comment: @user3663727 why do you call `get()`. It blocks the ui thread waiting for the result. Never block ui thread

Comment: wait friends i am posting my all codes then you will be able to understand properly

Comment: Please post your new problem with new question

Comment: Giru bai i am not unerstanding anything so i want to post my code wait a mintue